# Python scapy raw to hex

Tags: python, hex, scapy

I'm using Scapy to get raw bytes from packets and I'm trying to parse the hex, however the raw bytes give me this type of output:

b"\x17\x03\x03\x00\xa3\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xd6tK\xf8\xc1itQ\xa0;

Some of the string prints as ascii making it difficult to parse, is there a function to get just hex numbers in Scapy or convert this to hex and not print in ascii?

also, chexdump() for some reason only prints

Answer (score 2):

Yes you have :

> Use hexdump() to display one or more packets using classic hexdump
>   format

Ref:

```
https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/master/doc/scapy/usage.rst
```

Scapy is Python lib, then using generator:

```
>>> [ "%02X"%(ord(x) & 0xff) for x in b'\x20\x56\x30\20' ]
>>> ' '.join([ "0x%02X"%(ord(x) & 0xff) for x in b'\x20\x56\x30\20' ])
>>> ' '.join([ "%02X"%(ord(x) & 0xff) for x in b'\x20\x56\x30\20' ])
>>> ''.join([ "%02X"%(ord(x) & 0xff) for x in b'\x20\x56\x30\20' ])

>>> rawbuffer = b'\x20\x56\x30\20'
>>> bufferArray = [ "%02X"%(ord(x) & 0xff) for x in rawbuffer ]
>>> strbuffer = ''.join(bufferArray)
>>> print(strbuffer)
```

Comment: is it possible to use a variable for this? It seems to convert everything, i.e b"\x etc

Answer (score 0):

```
import binascii

binascii.hexlify(b"\x17\x03\x03\x00\xa3\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xd6tK\xf8\xc1itQ\xa0;")

#outputs => b'17030300a300000000000000d6744bf8c1697451a03b'
```

is one way that you can get a hex string out of a bytestring

if you really want it grouped into 2's

```
b" ".join(re.findall(b'..',binascii.hexlify(b"\x17\x03\x03\x00\xa3\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xd6tK\xf8\xc1itQ\xa0;")))
```

should work

Comment: The string is in a variable but the hexlify function doesn't seem to do anything to it. What could be the reason for this?